# How to display selected name in <p> from a Select dropdown and send selected id to controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have the following select input in my html which is populated using `ng-options`. I want to show the selected **NAME** down below in

whereas I want to send the selected **ID** back to the controller. I get the required id from `ng-model="user.category"`. How can I show the selected name? I also show the names in options.

```
<select ng-model="user.category" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories" class="form-control" class="select" required>
  <option value="{{category.name}}">Select a Category</option>
</select>

<p>Available On : {{user.retailerBranchId}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make retailerBranchId a method you can do it with something like lodash' _.find() (or even native find). You have user.category updating according to your selection, which you say has the id in it, which you can use:

```
function retailerBranchId() {
  return _.get(_.find(this.categories, { id: user.category }), 'name', '');
}
```

This also fails gracefully; if it can't find any name, or any item that matches the id, it'll return an empty string.

Edit: You would call it in a similar fashion like so:

```
<p>Available on: {{ user.retailerBranchId() }}</p>
```

Although really, it's better to use it like this:

```
<p data-ng-bind="'Available on: ' + user.retailerBranchId()"></p>
```

Comment: And how will I call this function?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select ng-model="user.category" ng-options="category for category in categories" class="form-control" class="select" required>
  <option value="{{category.name}}">Select a Category</option>
</select>
  
<p>Available On : {{user.category.id}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like a below method,

Controller to get selected Category Name:

```
$scope.getSelectedCategoryDetail=function(selectedCat){
   angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(cat){
      if(selectedCat===cat.id){
         $scope.user.name=cat.name;
      }
   });
};
```

Template to have ng-change event:

```
<select ng-model="user.category" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories" class="form-control" class="select" required>
  <option value="{{category.name}}" ng-change="getSelectedCategoryDetail(user.category)">Select a Category</option>
</select>


<p>Category Id : {{user.category}}</p>
<p>Category Name : {{user.name}}</p>
```